# How do I design the maximum current curve for a stepper motor?

Tags: current, stepper-motor

I want to drive a stepper motor (0.89V/5A) with the L6470H-controller. There I have to set different values for controlling the maximum voltage each for holding, running, speeding up and slowing down the stepper motor in the registers. Now I was wondering if I should choose different settings for the current for accelerating/deccelerating the motor than for running it on a continuous speed. Is there a reason for that, or should I rather simply set all registers to the same value?
While speeding up to the desired running speed, should I increase the maximum current, or should I rather stay at the same level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The \$L6470H\$ controls the current in the motor indirectly by means of the voltage motor, then setting these values you are specifying the desired maximum torque the motor should deliver at each driver state.